# Translating postcard written in German and sent either to/from Trebisov in Slovakia

Tags: palaeography, german, czechoslovakia, berlin

Postcard sent to from Trebisov, Slovakia, possibly  to Berlin , and from/to my great-uncle Marcusz Goldfischer

[image: Handwritten postcard]

I'm not sure,  I uploaded correctly,  but there is an image of a woman on the front.
(There are two words in Hebrew script, on the second to bottom row- left side-  which are a lofty way of saying "wife" in Hebrew.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote down what I can read, as I'm unsure about some letters. The orthography is a bit adventurous.

```
Zur ewigen andenken              "to remember forever" [that's what probably meant]
habe ich das erhalten            I received this
von meiner l**stube?             from my ???

Trebisov 2 Mai                   Trebisov 2 May
Markus Golafischer               ...

für Moral und Tugend             for moral and virtue
Erünerung an unserer Jugend      reminder
Schönheit leider vergeht,        beauty alas dies
[hebräisch] auf immer besteht    [hebrew] exists forever
Obiger                           the above
```

Comment: _von meiner lieben_ [a female name with E]?

Comment: "von meiner l. Estike", maybe?